# asp.net Global variables and session variable lose value after 5-15 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am not sure why but only after a certain amount of time, My web application global variables lose value and also the session variables as well. I set in the web config file  `<sessionState timeout="60"  />`. This is on my local host i have not put this out on a web server yet, could this be the cause?

Comment: What is the timeout of the sessionstate in your web config?  It would lose context after that much time of inactivity has passed.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Multiple requests can touch them at the same time, and that means multiple different users can touch them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with inproc session state, if the app pool recycles or shuts down, your session information is gone.  check iis settings for when app pool recycles happen.  i believe there is a default to shut down the app pool after 20 minutes of inactivity.  there are many other reasons this can happen.  if you need session to live beyond the life of your app pool, you should take it out of proc and run in state server or database or something else custom.

Comment: I have a windows 7 computer where do I go to check IIS?

Comment: open the iis manager (easiest way is to hit the windows key and just start typing iis - it will appear in the list).  in the tree view on the left under your machine name, you will see a node for application pools.  clicking on that will show the app pools in the list view on the right.  click on your app pool and then click the Advanced Settings... link on the right.  you will see things in the like Private Memory Lmiit (KB), Idle Time-out (minutes) , Request Limit, Regular Time Interval (minutes).  these things control recycling of the app pool.

Comment: I guess this doesnt apply if you are using localhost, i do not see iis anywhere in my admin tools.

Answer (score 1):

In case it runs in IIS, do you have `Regular Time Interval (minutes)` or `Idle Time-out (minutes)` to a low value? These settings can be found under `Advanced Settings...` of your application pool.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem but you can add the following to the page's OnInit to determine whether or not the session has actually timed out or not:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the base Page class.
    base.OnInit(e);
    //If the session exists
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        // IsNewSession indicates the session has been reset or the user's session has timed out.
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            // new session, check for a cookie. 
            string cookie = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            // If there is a cookie does it contain ASP.NET Session ID? 
            if ((null != cookie) &&
                (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {
                // Since it's a new session but an ASP.NET cookie exists, the session has expired. Notify the user.  
                throw new Exception("Your session has timed out. ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```